# How to evalute an exponential tower modulo a prime

Tags: algorithm, math, language-agnostic

I want to find a fast algorithm to evaluate an expression like the following, where *P* is prime.

```
A ^ B ^ C ^ D ^ E mod P
```

Example:

```
(9 ^ (3 ^ (15 ^ (3 ^ 15)))) mod 65537 = 16134
```

The problem is the intermediate results can grow much too large to handle.

Comment: Type to Matlab and there you go. :)

Comment: How is this programming related?

Comment: Is P prime?  It might help.

Comment: I'm interested in details.

Comment: @FelixKling OP wants to find an algorithm for calculating such expressions.  That's one relation to programming.  If you're looking for application domains, cryptography is one.

Comment: @Cruelbob: That's all I wanted to know. I wanted you to [edit] your question and clarify it. Because as it is, the answer could also be "use tool X to solve such expressions" which is *not* programming related.

Comment: That's not my field of expertise, but my first thought was some clever usage of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat's_little_theorem).  Here are some basics of [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation), but of course you're asking for something more advanced.

Comment: @NiklasB. thx, I believe you

Comment: I updated with the result of a question I asked on Math exchange that improves the run time of the algorithm.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [finding a^b^c^... mod m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223313/finding-abc-mod-m)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Basically the problem reduces to computing `a^T mod m` for given `a`, `m` and a term `T` that is ridiulously huge. However, we are able to evaluate `T mod n` with a given modulus `n` much faster than `T` . So we ask: "Is there an integer `n`, such that `a^(T mod n) mod m = a^T mod m`?"

Now if `a` and `m` are coprime, we know that `n = phi(m)` fulfills our condition according to [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem):

```
  a^T                               (mod m)
= a^((T mod phi(m)) + k * phi(m))   (mod m)    (for some k)
= a^(T mod phi(m)) * a^(k * phi(m)) (mod m)
= a^(T mod phi(m)) * (a^phi(m))^k   (mod m)
= a^(T mod phi(m)) * 1^k            (mod m)
= a^(T mod phi(m))                  (mod m)
```

If we can compute `phi(m)` (which is easy to do for example in `O(m^(1/2))` or if we know the prime factorization of `m`), we have reduced the problem to computing `T mod phi(m)` and a simple [modular exponentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).

What if `a` and `m` are not coprime? The situation is not as pleasant as before, since there might not be a valid `n` with the property `a^T mod m = a^(T mod n) mod m` for all `T`. However, we can show that the sequence `a^k mod m` for `k = 0, 1, 2, ...` enters a cycle after some point, that is there exist `x` and `C` with `x, C < m`, such that `a^y = a^(y + C)` for all `y >= x`.

**Example**: For `a = 2, m = 12`, we get the sequence `2^0, 2^1, ... = 1, 2, 4, 8, 4, 8, ... (mod 12)`. We can see the cycle with parameters `x = 2` and `C = 2`.

We can find the cycle length via brute-force, by computing the sequence elements `a^0, a^1, ...` until we find two indices `X < Y` with `a^X = a^Y`. Now we set `x = X` and `C = Y - X`. This gives us an algorithm with `O(m)` exponentiations per recursion.

What if we want to do better? Thanks to [Jyrki Lahtonen](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/11619/jyrki-lahtonen) from Math Exchange for providing [the essentials for the following algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653696/15462)!

Let's evaluate the sequence `d_k = gcd(a^k, m)` until we find an `x` with `d_x = d_{x+1}`. This will take at most `log(m)` GCD computations, because `x` is bounded by the highest exponent in the prime factorization of `m`. Let `C = phi(m / d_x)`. [We can now prove that](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/653696/15462) `a^{k + C} = a^k` for all `k >= x`, so we have found the cycle parameters in `O(m^(1/2))` time.

Let's assume we have found `x` and `C` and want to compute `a^T mod m` now. 
If `T < x`, the task is trivial to perform with simple modular exponentiation. Otherwise, we have `T >= x` and can thus make use of the cycle:

```
  a^T                                     (mod m)
= a^(x + ((T - x) mod C))                 (mod m)
= a^(x + (-x mod C) + (T mod C) + k*C)    (mod m)     (for some k)
= a^(x + (-x mod C) + k*C) * a^(T mod C)  (mod m)
= a^(x + (-x mod C)) * a^(T mod C)        (mod m)
```

Again, we have reduced the problem to a subproblem of the same form ("compute `T mod C`") and two simple modular exponentiations.

Since the modulus is reduced by at least 1 in every iteration, we get a pretty weak bound of `O(P^(1/2) * min (P, n))` for the runtime of this algorithm, where `n` is the height of the stack. In practice we should get a lot better, since the moduli are expected to decrease exponentially. Of course this argument is a bit hand-wavy, maybe some more mathematically-inclined person can improve on it.

There are a few edge cases to consider that actually make your life a bit easier: you can stop immediately if `m = 1` (the result is 0 in this case) or if `a` is a multiple of `m` (the result is 0 as well in this case).

**EDIT:** It can be shown that `x = C = phi(m)` is valid, so as a quick and dirty solution we can use the formula

```
a^T = a^(phi(m) + T mod phi(m))  (mod m)
```

for `T >= phi(m)` or even `T >= log_2(m)`.