# How do i compute a prime power tower modulo to m

Tags: algorithm, math, primes, number-theory, modular-arithmetic

Here is the problem - i have been given a prime number P and a number K. I need to compute P ^ P ^ P ... k times modulo to m.

Here P is a prime number.

```
(P ^ (P ^ (P ^ P .... k times))) % m
```

Few examples

for P = 2, K = 3, m = 3

```
2 ^ 2 ^ 2 % 3 = 1
```

for P = 5, K = 3, m = 3

```
5 ^ 5 ^ 5 % 3 = 2
```

I can do a brute force but the problem is the numbers can become very large.

here are the contraints

```
2 <= p < 10 ^ 8
1 <= k < 10 ^ 8 
1 <= m <= 10 ^ 8
```

Comment: How big can `p` and `k` get?

Comment: @IVlad 2<=p< 10^8 and 1 <= k <= 10^8

Comment: Do you want to compute `[(p^p)^p]^p ... k times` or `p^(p^[p^...]...) k times`?

Comment: How big can m get?

Comment: @PaulHankin m is within range of prime p.

Comment: The problem would be easier if m was prime. You want to use the fact that a^phi(m) = 1 mod m, if gcd(a,m) = 1.

Comment: I just watched a youtube video on this... [How to Break Cryptography](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=12Q3Mrh03Gk)

Comment: @IVlad for p = 5, k = 3 find (5 ^ (5 ^ 5)) % m

Comment: @JamesKPolk fortunately, our `a` is prime, so `m` doesn't have to be.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I think that makes it only slightly easier: it reduces the problem to computing p^..^p (k-1 times) mod phi(m), but when you try to solve this, phi(m) won't be prime. But I guess that approach works, and phi(phi(...(m))) will quickly reduce to 1.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to compute a^^b mod m?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713648/how-to-compute-ab-mod-m)

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the exponentiation is left associative, meaning you have to compute:

```
[(p^p)^p]^p ... k times
```

---

**Note:** if this is a wrong assumption, then your question is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713648/how-to-compute-ab-mod-m). In fact, yours is easier, since `p` is prime.

---

Then this is equal to:

```
p^(p*p*p*... k times)
```

Which is equal to:

```
p^(p^k)
```

Using [exponentiation by squaring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) this is doable in `O(log p^k) = O(k log p)`

But, this is still too much for your stated limits of `p, k < 10^8`.

In order to make it better, you can use some information from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30713648/how-to-compute-ab-mod-m) by [Douglas Zare](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2363540/douglas-zare):

> you could say that a^k mod m = a^(k mod phi(m)) mod m. However, this is not always true when a and m are not relatively prime

Fortunately, `a = p` in our case, and `p` is prime, so that holds.

So your problem reduces to computing:

```
p^(p^k mod phi(m)) mod m
```

Requiring two exponentiations by squaring, which is easily doable.

See [how to compute the totient function efficiently](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/eulers-totient-function/):

```
int phi(int n)
{    
    int result = n;   // Initialize result as n

    // Consider all prime factors of n and subtract their
    // multiples from result
    for (int p=2; p*p<=n; ++p)
    {
        // Check if p is a prime factor.
        if (n % p == 0)
        {
            // If yes, then update n and result 
            while (n % p == 0)
                n /= p;
            result -= result / p;
        }
    }

    // If n has a prime factor greater than sqrt(n)
    // (There can be at-most one such prime factor)
    if (n > 1)
        result -= result / n;
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Without any additional information I think x^x^x is x^(x^x) and NOT (x^x)^x... this would be much simpler. At least if a mathematician writes it, he means the former.

Comment: @maraca yes, he clarified it's the latter. In that case, it's a duplicate of the linked question. I have made my answer CW just in case someone is interested in this version.