# Finding (a ^ x) % m from a % m. This is about utilizing a % m to calculate (a ^ x) % m. % is the modulus operator

Tags: math, recursion, biginteger, modulus, largenumber

I have `a % m.` I want to find a<sup>x</sup> % m.

This is what I have observed.

```
Let a = 6 and m = 4

a % m = 2
```

We can find a<sup>2</sup> % m as (6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6 + 6) % m which is equal to

```
((6 % 4) + (6 % 4) + (6 % 4) + (6 % 4) + (6 % 4) + (6 % )) % 4 which is 0
```

This can be seen as 6<sup>2</sup> % 4 = (6 * (6 % 4) % 4

For 3 the above can be written as (6 * ((6 * (6 % 4)) % 4)) % 4

This can be done like that recursively.

Is there an efficient method than this ?

Comment: Are you looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation? There are examples of pseudocode in the article.

Comment: Ohh does it have a name !!

Comment: @AlexRiley those pseudocodes are same as what I have asked in the question. I'm looking for an efficient method.

Comment: [How to compute a^^b mod m?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30713648/995714), [Calculating (a^b)%MOD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11272437/995714)

Comment: @bharath: those are the efficient methods.

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc those questions were about calculating (a ^ x ) % m but you can see that my question is calculating (a ^ x) % m from (a % m)

Comment: @bharath that's the same thing.

Comment: function name is `modpow` and algorithm name is [power by squaring](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30962495/2521214) with slight change and that is it uses modulus arithmetics like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214) instead of standard one