# Calculating a^b^c mod 10^9+7

Tags: c++, exponentiation, modular

Problem Link - https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1712

input -

```
1
7
8
10
```

- Expected Output - `928742408`
- My output - `989820350`

point that is confusing me - Out of 100s of inputs, in only 1 or 2 test cases my code is providing wrong output, if the code is wrong shouldn't it give wrong output for everything?

My code -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

typedef unsigned long long ull;
constexpr auto N = 1000000007;

using namespace std;

ull binpow(ull base, ull pwr) {
    base %= N;
    ull res = 1;
    while (pwr > 0) {
        if (pwr & 1)
            res = res * base % N;
        base = base * base % N;
        pwr >>= 1;
    }
    return res;
}

ull meth(ull a, ull b, ull c) {
    if (a == 0 && (b == 0 || c == 0))
        return 1;
    if (b == 0 && c == 0)
        return 1;
    if (c == 0)
        return a;

    ull pwr = binpow(b, c);
    ull result = binpow(a, pwr);

    return result;
}

int main() {

    ios_base::sync_with_stdio(0);
    cin.tie(0);
    ull a, b, c, n;
    cin >> n;

    for (ull i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cin >> a >> b >> c;
        cout << meth(a, b, c) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
`
```

Comment: If I am not wrong, b^c must be canculated `mod N-1` and not `mod N`. The order of the multiplicity group of GF(N) is N-1

Comment: "in only 1 or 2 test cases my code is providing wrong output,"  --> What is the other wrong output?

Comment: "if the code is wrong shouldn't it give wrong output for everything?" - Absolutely not. Wrong code outputs right results all the time. Just because it's wrong doesn't mean it always has to output the wrong result.

Comment: The idea is that x^(N-1) = 1 mod N, if N is prime

Comment: [How to compute a^b^c mod p?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46944581/995714), [How to evalute an exponential tower modulo a prime](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21367824/995714), [finding a^b^c^… mod m](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4223313/995714)

Comment: @Damien, yes, it worked

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is based on an incorrect mathematical assumption. If you want to compute a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup> mod m you can't reduce the exponent b<sup>c</sup> mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 7. In other words, a<sup>b<sup>c</sup></sup> mod m != a<sup>b<sup>c</sup> mod m</sup> mod m. Instead, you can reduce it mod 10<sup>9</sup> + 6 which works because of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem). Therefore, you need to compute your exponent b<sup>c</sup> under a different modulus.

Answer (score 0):

For reference

---

Change

```
ull pwr = binpow(b, c);
```

To a pwr = b<sup>c</sup> calculation.

8<sup>10</sup> --> ‭1,073,741,824‬

7<sup>‭1,073,741,824‬</sup> mod 100000007 --> 928742408

---

> if the code is wrong shouldn't it give wrong output for everything?

Likely the other b<sup>c</sup> were always < 100000007

Comment: That will overflow very quickly since the numbers in the problem can be up to 1e9.

Comment: @BessieTheCow Fair enough.  Yet the goal is to point out what is wrong.  Up to OP to fix.

Comment: It worked, by reducing my Mod to mod-1 for power calculation