# How to compute a^b^c mod p?

Tags: math, exponentiation, modulo

I am trying to compute a^b^c mod p for some positive integers a,b,c,p. One possible (and obvious) way is to use fast modular exponentiation which will run in `O(log(b^c))=clog(b)`. While I don't mind the efficiency here, the obvious downfall of this method is that you need an explicit binary representation of `b^c` which in itself is already exponential.

So the question for me is, if  I can not represent `b^c` as a binary representation, is there a way I can compute `a^b^c` mod p from the binary representations of `a,b, and c`?

Comment: "can not represent b^c as a binary representation" - could you expand on this please

Comment: @JesseBarnett From a programmatical point of view. For instance b=2 and c=200, the number cannot be "stored" as a binary representation inside the native datatypes of C++ for instance.

Comment: im not really following why this is a problem. `#include cmath` and then once you have defined your variables, `answer = pow(pow(a,b),c) % p` doesn't work?

Comment: Iff you know the factorization of p you can compute its Euler totient and a^x mod p = a^(x mod totient(p)) mod p for x = b^c is much easier/faster; see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1626/modular-exponentiation-using-euler-s-theorem . If you do it on a computer even bignums are usually still binary though.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 But that assumes a and p are coprime. For me its not always the case

Comment: @JesseBarnett What you did would calculate a^(bc) mod p and not a^b^c mod p. Here, the a is multiplied b^c times, not a^b multiplied c times

Comment: Hmm... it feels to me like there should be a way to eliminate the common factors and reduce to a case where Euler/Fermat works, but I don't remember enough number theory to prove it. You might try that part on the math Stack.

Comment: If a and p are not co-prime then you'll still want to use Euler's totient function. Just compute a^(b^c) mod each prime power and use the chinese remainder theorem (CRT) to compute the answer. Or, more simply, if d=gcd(a, p), then compute a^x mod (p/d) where x = (b^c) mod ϕ(p/d) and use the CRT to get the answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [finding a^b^c^... mod m](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223313/finding-abc-mod-m)

Comment: @JesseBarnett that just works for tiny numbers. There are ways to do that for big numbers much efficiently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(a^b^c) mod p = (((a^b) mod p)^c) mod p
```

So you can do

```
modpow(modpow(a,b,p),c,p);
```

Where all operands results and subresults are normal ints. As `modpow` you can use power by squaring in modulo `p` like here:

- [Modular arithmetics and NTT (finite field DFT) optimizations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18577076/2521214)

beware those are a bit optimized taking advantage of the properties of specific selected `p` so you need to change lines like

```
if (DWORD(d)>=DWORD(p)) d-=p;
```

into

```
d%=p;
```

**[Example]**

```
(2^3^5) % 6 = 
(8  ^5) % 6 =
  32768 % 6 = 2

(((2^3)%6)^5) % 6 = 
((   8 %6)^5) % 6 = 
(    2    ^5) % 6 =
    32        % 6 = 2
```

Comment: This calculated a^(bc) mod p NOT a^b^c. Here, a is multiplied to itself b^c times!

Comment: never mind thanks for the answer, i got slightly confused. So this runs in log(b)log(c) correct?

Comment: @AspiringMat  For normal `int` variables the complexity is `O(log(b)+log(c))` if we assume both exponents are limited by `n` then the complexity is `O(log(n))`. For `bigint`  operands however operations `+,-,*,/` are not `O(1)` anymore so the complexity is much worse in such case.

Comment: @AspiringMat Also if you want to compute `a^(b^c) mod p` instead then this will not work and you need to use the linked possible duplicate.

Comment: This answer is incorrect. (a^b^c) mod p is *not* equal to (((a^b) mod p)^c) mod p

Comment: @JamesKPolk if your mean `((a^b)^c) mod p` ? for that you're right but the OP is about `a^b^c mod p` or need to edit the equation properly if not.

Comment: @Spektre: The expression `a^b^c` is almost always (in mathematics and in programming) interpreted as `a^(b^c)`, not as `(a^b)^c`. The OP is clearly working with the `a^(b^c)` interpretation, since the question mentions computing `b^c` as a substep.

Comment: @JamesKPolk On the other hand OP's first comment here suggest you're right guys ... (making the question duplicate) ... However Looks like I can not delete accepted answer ....

Comment: I agree it's not completely clear, that's why I didn't downvote. I just guessed from his discussion that he meant a^(b^c).

Comment: I ended up addapting your method. So I write a^b^c as a^(b*b*..*b) so i first compute a^b mod p then I calculate (a^b mod p)^b mod p and so on. This runs in O(c log b)

Comment: @AspiringMat `O(n.log(m))` `n` is number of nested modpows and `m` is limit of the input variables size (`log(m)` is the bitwidth of your variables) .

Answer (score 0):

https://discuss.codechef.com/t/compute-a-b-c-mod-p/1989
check this page, after solve https://cses.fi/problemset/task/1712 .
The above answer **modpow(modpow(a,b,p),c,p);**  looks very logical ,
but it won't work(you can verify it through CSES problem mentioned above). Use this formula/method **modpow(a,modpow(b,c,p-1),p);** .
They use Fermat's theorem to derive  this **modpow(a,modpow(b,c,p-1),p);** .
By the way cpp code is as follows :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define ar array
#define int long long
using namespace std;

const int mxN=2e5+2,mxM=1003,M=1e9+7;

int pM(int n,int p,int M)
{
    int res=1;
    while(p)
    {
        if(p&1)
            res=res*n%M;
        n=n*n%M;
        p>>=1;
    }
    return res;
}
signed main()
{
    int t;
    cin>>t;
    while(t--)
    {
         int a,b,c;
        cin>>a>>b>>c;
        cout<<pM(a,pM(b,c,M-1),M)<<"\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```